# Path of include

Tags: php

I am a bit desperate because I am trying to include a file, in my webpage everything works fine, except the next issue.

My map

```
root (BitsInteligencia is the folder, into wamp/www/)
-admin
--admin.php
-includes
--categories.php
--conection.php
--header.php
index.php
...
```

My header

```
<?php      
include("../BitsInteligencia/includes/config.php");
// Title
echo "<title>Bits de Inteligencia</title>";
// Config
// Responsive and other options
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>";
echo "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";
// Scripts JQuery or JavaScript
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src=" . PATH_SCRIPT_JQUERY . "></script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src=" . PATH_SCRIPT_BOOTSRAP . "></script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src=" . PATH_SCRIPT_CARROUSEL . "></script>";
// CSS
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=" . PATH_CSS_STYLE . ">";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=" . PATH_CSS_BOOTSTRAP . ">";
echo "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
?>
```

And my config.php

```
   // Paths
   define('PATH_CSS_STYLE', '../BitsInteligencia/css/style.css');
   define('PATH_CSS_BOOTSTRAP', '../BitsInteligencia/css/bootstrap.min.css');
   define('PATH_SCRIPT_JQUERY', '../BitsInteligencia/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');
   define('PATH_SCRIPT_BOOTSRAP', '../BitsInteligencia/scripts/bootstrap.min.js');
   define('PATH_SCRIPT_CARROUSEL', '../BitsInteligencia/scripts/carrousel.js');
```

In my admin.php i use

```
  <?php
     include("BitsInteligencia/includes/header.php");
  ?>
```

But It doesnt work fine, the server show me an error because it cant see the file. I have tried everything:

- include_once
- use ../
- use .
- use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
- use includes/header.php
- use /includes/header.php
- etc.

When I access to other page, for example, from the root (bits.php) everthing works fine.

I dont know where is my problem, and advice?

Sorry, i have tried to format the php code but i don´t know how is it.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've two questions.

1. Is there a folder at root named **BitsInteligencia**? and is **includes** folder is a subfolder of **BitsInteligencia**?
2. Are you directly accessing the file **admin/admin.php**?

If you are accessing the file **admin/admin.php** directly, then you should call the **header.php** file as below

```
// If "includes" is subfolder of "BitsInteligencia"
<?php
    include("../BitsInteligencia/includes/header.php");
?>

// If "includes" is not subfolder of "BitsInteligencia"
<?php
    include("../includes/header.php");
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. As you have said, my root folder is BitInteligencia, so i have done that you said and then the server showed other error about pearl, i followed this instructions to solve: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29976/install-pear-on-windows-7-64x-using-wamp/